# How to check if variable is function in a javascript class method without using eval

Tags: javascript

i have created this class to check if the function has been loaded. It works fine, except that I want to avoid using eval to evaluate the function name from a variable. I appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

```
class scriptLoader {

constructor(fn, max_try) {        
    this.fn = fn; //the func name being passed as a string
    this.count = 0; //init count start value                
    this.max_try = max_try; //the max times to try
}



waitForScriptToLoad() {           
      'use strict';        
        let my_function = eval(this.fn); //this evaluate the string, i.e 'myfunc' to myfunc()                       
      if(typeof my_function === "function") {                        
        my_function();
    } else {                                    
        if(this.count<this.max_try) {
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function() {that.count++; that.waitForScriptToLoad();},100); //wait 100ms and try again            
        } else {                
            return false;                
        }            
    }
}
```

}

I instantiate the class like so:

```
loadData = new scriptLoader('Worker.fetch_form_data', 3);
loadData.waitForScriptToLoad();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the script you're trying to detect will be located on the global object, split the string by `.`s and check to see if the nested property exists on the global object:

```js
class scriptLoader {

  constructor(propsStr, max_try) {
    this.propsStr = propsStr; //the func name being passed as a string
    this.count = 0; //init count start value                
    this.max_try = max_try; //the max times to try
  }
  waitForScriptToLoad() {
    'use strict';
    const possibleFn = this.propsStr.split('.').reduce((a, prop) => (a?.[prop]), globalThis);
    if (typeof possibleFn === "function") {
      possibleFn();
    } else {
      if (this.count < this.max_try) {
        console.log('retrying');
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.count++;
          this.waitForScriptToLoad();
        }, 100); //wait 100ms and try again            
      }
    }
  }
}

// Dynamic loading of script:
setTimeout(() => {
  window.obj = {};
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
  window.obj.nested = {
    fn: () => console.log('fn')
  };
}, 150);


const loadData = new scriptLoader('obj.nested.fn', 3);
loadData.waitForScriptToLoad();
```

Also note:

- If using ES2015+ syntax (which you are, and you should be!), best to use `const` rather than `let` if you don't require reassignment - avoid `var`
- In ES2015+, better to use an arrow function than the `that = this` antipattern
- Remember to declare your variables when using them - your `loadData` is implicitly global since you didn't declare it (consider enabling strict mode at the top level)

Comment: It works, Thanks! But first i got to understand how reduce works.